# Changing text to date on pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a text column with the format of dd-mmm-yy (e.g.01-Jun-22) for the date.
I tried the following code:

```
df['new_date'] = df['date_text'].dt.strftime('%d/%b/%y')
```

I'm using this table as a guide (https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) but I got the following error: AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values.
Will appreciate any advice.

Comment: It seems your `'date_text'` value is TEXT and not a Datetime object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the date into a `datetime` object before you would be able to format it the way you wish.

Pandas has a very convenient `to_datetime` function that is usually smart enough to recognize the date format in the whole dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date_text': ['01-Jun-22', '02-Jun-22']})
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_text'])
df['new_text'] = df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%d/%b/%y')
```

Would produce

```
   date_text   datetime   new_text
0  01-Jun-22 2022-06-01  01/Jun/22
1  02-Jun-22 2022-06-02  02/Jun/22
```